# Remotely Installing Windows 2008 on SunBlade 6000/6250... any gotchas?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sun, provisioning, netboot, windows-pe

I'm preparing to remotely install Windows 2008 Standard onto a 6250 blade module mounted in a **[SunBlade 6000](http://www.sun.com/servers/blades/6000/)** chassis rack.

Are there any gotchas (aside from the predictable issues related to bandwidth in transferring the ISO, etc.) for this?  Has anyone else successfully completed this task?

I'm not a hardware guy, I'm a software guy who has been handed this task because the guys in the datacenter don't want to touch it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wow.  It's never occurred to me to consider putting Windows on a Sun box...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb, since I haven't ever done this myself, but if the blade supports network booting (which it must), and you have a proper `unattend.txt` for the installation, you should be fine.

I'm going to assume that WinPE will handle the hardware OK - though I'd make sure you have all the appropriate drivers for the blade hardware ready :)